# How to unit test conditions which depend on non existence of a library which is present on the testing machine

Tags: r, unit-testing, testthat

Let's assume I have the following function:

```r
f <- function() if (requireNamespace("utils")) 1 else 0
```

How would I use `test_that` to see whether `0` is properly returned in case `utils` would not be installed (N.B. I used `utils` in this to example to make it a `reprex` knowing that `utils` is always installed)?

I could think of the following solution:

```r
library(testthat)

test_that("`f` returns 0 if `utils` is not found", {
   f_env <- environment(f)
   tmp_env <- new.env(parent = f_env)
   tmp_env$requireNamespace <- function(...) FALSE
   environment(f) <- tmp_env
   expect_equal(f(), 0)
})
# Test passed
```

This feels somehow hackish as it creates a copy of `f`, so I was wondering what would be the canonical solution for such a case?

---

### Update

As apparently it was not quite clear what I want to achieve, I try to re-phrase:

1. My code uses a clause like this:

   ```
   if (!requireNamespace("some_pkg")) {
      ### do something
   }
   ```
2. On my system `some_pkg` is installed, thus the code block will naturally never be executed in my unit tests, unless I de-install library `some_pkg`.
3. Hence, I was using the workaround in the example, but was wondering whether there are other techniques for that.

Comment: Revealing how very little I know, why not use `f()`, in case of `maaakiji`, `f2()` in case of `utils`, directly as functions, which relieves the environment swapping, `test_that('f2' returns 1 if 'utils' is found', { 
f2_expect <- expect_equal(f2(), 1)
expect_equal(f2_expect, 1)
})
Test passed`, though the expect_equal is run twice to get the gratifying `Test passed`, so copying going on here as well. Ah well.

Comment: `test_that('f2 returns 1 if utils is found', {
eval(expect_equal(f2(), 1))
 })
Test passed` eliminates need for second expect_equal.

Comment: Hi Chris, I think I did not really grasp what you meant, could you re-explain?

Comment: Well, I guess I finally understand your problem of when TRUE, FALSE, (utils is always there) and explains `tmp_env$requireNamespace <- function(...) FALSE` that I puzzled over. So I guess my question is if the use case is restricted just to the testing machine and not extending to say my pkg user computer [missing depends not found case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68687822/installing-package-x12#comment121389723_68687822). We see something like you approach in [pkgndep](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pkgndep/vignettes/pkgndep.html). Smarter than me hopefully weigh in.

Comment: Maybe I was too abstract in my toy example (will fix that in my post). What I want is 1. have a `requireNamespace(<somePkg>)` if clause in my code, but also to be able to `test_that` on my machine (where `somePkg` is installed))

Comment: Your approach addresses the test machine problem nicely. I was suggesting that functions, given they provide their own, temporary environment, should be sufficient for 'in the wild'.